# Add timestamps to "top" command output

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, timestamps, top

I'm extracting some performance metrics from "top" and saving them into file

```
top -b | grep 'tesseract\|node\|java\|beam.smp\|dockerd' > testm.txt
```

so for every second I'm getting next output:

```
   535 rabbitmq  20   0 1246756 128432   5536 S   1.3  3.4 618:33.41 beam.smp
   589 root      20   0  351040  47836  25740 S   0.0  1.3  12:38.72 dockerd
  1980 root      20   0 2236796  36844  15980 S   0.0  1.0   6:11.59 java
  1995 root      20   0 1766008 241428  21844 S   0.0  6.4  11:26.85 java
 29965 root      20   0 1107460  63732  19328 S   0.0  1.7   0:01.69 node
```

I'm curious how to add timestamps for every chunk of this output, because when running this script for a long period of time it become impossible to find out when some random data chunk had been collected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `ts`: `top -b | grep 'tesseract\|node\|java\|beam.smp\|dockerd | ts ...`

Comment: `top` already has a timestamp'ish on the topmost line: `top - 20:11:51 up 10 days, ...` FWIW

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a timestamp to each line of top output for an individual run of `top -b` can be easily done using `awk` instead of grep for your filtering, because [`awk` has time functions built in](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), and can inject them into it's output.

*I'm not running most of these programs, so I've added `bash` and `ssh` to the filter in my examples...*

You can do it with a simple epoch timestamp (seconds since 01-JAN-1970):

```
top -b | awk '/bash|ssh|tesseract|node|java|beam.smp|dockerd/ {print systime(), $0}'
```

Which is smaller to store, and cleaner to look at:

```
bash-$ top -b | awk '/bash|ssh|tesseract|node|java|beam.smp|dockerd/ {print systime(), $0}'
1490018813  1229 root      20   0  891536  42868  28348 S   0.0  0.3  15:07.30 dockerd
1490018813  1240 root      20   0   65520   6208   5488 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 sshd
1490018813  2666 tim       20   0   24336   7136   3492 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 bash
1490018813  2710 tim       20   0   46984   5324   4644 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.08 ssh
1490018813  2783 root      20   0  105988   7184   6184 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
1490018813  2804 root      20   0  105988   7404   6408 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
```

Or with a more human readable timestamp.

```
top -b | awk '/bash|ssh|tesseract|node|java|beam.smp|dockerd/ {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S", systime(), $0}'
```

Which is faster to understand:

```
bash-[541]$ top -b -n 3 | awk '/ssh|bash|java|dockerd/ {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S", systime()), $0}'
2017-03-20-10:04:23  1229 root      20   0  891536  42868  28348 S   0.0  0.3  15:07.24 dockerd
2017-03-20-10:04:23  1240 root      20   0   65520   6208   5488 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 sshd
2017-03-20-10:04:23  2666 tim       20   0   24336   7136   3492 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 bash
2017-03-20-10:04:23  2710 tim       20   0   46984   5324   4644 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.08 ssh
2017-03-20-10:04:23  2783 root      20   0  105988   7184   6184 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
2017-03-20-10:04:23  2804 root      20   0  105988   7404   6408 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
2017-03-20-10:04:23  2909 tim       20   0  105988   5072   4072 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.20 sshd
2017-03-20-10:04:23  2931 tim       20   0  105988   4252   3224 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
```